# Refunding gift copy in Steam of game already owned

Tags: steam

So, I had bought a few copies of a game for some friends, but I accidentally bought an extra one and I want to get a refund on that extra

Will steam only take that one out and not mess with the copy that I've already owned for awhile now and the others that have been claimed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it never left your inventory and is still there, you can refund a game by selecting `A purchase` when using the refund interface.

[image: screenshot]

From there, you can select the copy in your inventory. It will have a little box icon, showing that it was a gift:

[image: screenshot]

Now it should show you something like this:

[image: screenshot recipts]

Click on "view receipt" for the one that was not redeemed:

[image: confirmation number]

From there, go through with your refund request.

Comment: @HyenaNoises I made an extensive edit. That should be good enough to get your refund.

Comment: Thank ya, it does! Though I do admit, I've kind of changed my mind on getting a refund since it was such a small amount of money. But the info will still be handy to know in the future!

Comment: @HyenaNoises LOL, ok. Just leave the question here, it might prove useful for others. And you might want to accept my answer.